# return new object in es6 with map

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to loop through an array of objects to pull out the "leaf" object and create a new array of objects.

My code looks like this:

```
        let topic_data_leaf = topicData.hits.hits.map((hit) => { return hit._source })

        console.log("topic leaf": topic_data_leaf);
```

`topic_data_leaf` has the following structure:

```
hits: {
    hits: [
     {_id: "id12345"
      _index: "index1"
      _score: 5.7439504
      _source: {field1: val1, field2: val2}
      _type: "kafka"
     }   
    [
}
```

I want to pull out the objects in the `_source` field and create a new array of those objects.

Comment: That's what your code does, as far as we can tell (you have some typos, like the `:` in the `console.log` and a `[` at the end of your array where I'm guessing you meant a `]`). What's the question?

Comment: oh sorry...the `console.log` comes back as undefined...I can't seem to see the typo either....where is that??

Comment: The `console.log` above doesn't do anything, because it never runs. (Syntax error.) If we fix various basic syntax errors, your `map` works just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/dsrcbtba/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because wasn't an error...typo in the question

Comment: `topic_data_leaf`, the result of the `map` invocation, is an array. Are you sure you haven't shown us the `topicData`?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine, other than the few minor errors you've got.

```
let topic_data_leaf = topicData.hits.hits.map((hit) => { return hit._source })

console.log("topic leaf:", topic_data_leaf); // the colon shouldn't be outside the string
```

Also make sure your objects are actually correct:

```
hits: {
    hits: [
     {_id: "id12345"
      _index: "index1"
      _score: 5.7439504
      _source: {field1: val1, field2: val2}
      _type: "kafka"
     }   
    ] // this line was '[' in your code
}
```

This should function correctly now.